# Understanding a question about gradient on corresponding level sets

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

I am having difficulty understanding what this question is asking for, and was wondering if someone could shed some light on it.

> $f: \mathbb R^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined by
>
> $f(x, y, z)=z^{2} - x^{2} - y^{2}$
>
> Define the level set of $f$ for the value c to be
>
> $\sum_{c} := \{x \in \mathbb R : f(x) = c \}$
>
> Compute $\nabla f$. **Indicate $\nabla f$ as a vector at the points $(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ on the corresponding level sets.**

I know that $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (-2x, -2y, 2z)$. Is the question asking for the value of $\nabla f$ at the points  $(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ or does it want to be expressed in terms of these points, or something else entirely?

Comment: I think it's saying to substitute x,y,z all by 1 after you find the gradient. As in, $\nabla f(x,y,z)_{(1,1,1)} = (-2x,-2y,2z)_{(1,1,1)} = (-2,-2,2)$

Comment: Hmm alright, thanks. Would the "corresponding level sets" be the level set  that $(-2, -2, 2)$ is a part of then?

Comment: I guess. That's what makes most sense. I agree that the person who asked the question could've been a wee-bit clearer than that.